# Does the non-trivial solution set of a homogenous equation always represents a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

In *David C. Lay- Linear Algebra and Its Applications- Pearson Education (2005)*, it is mentioned that:

This is the figure 2:

[image: Figure 2]

> A plane through the origin, as in Fig. 2, provides
>   a good mental image for the solution set of Ax = 0 when there are two or more free
>   variables.

Why would a solution set of Ax=0, when there are, say three free variables will represent a plane? Won't it represent a 3D space?

Comment: We dont know what  $A$ and $x$  mean in the book.

Comment: @Gribouillis A is the coefficient matrix and x is the variable matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The solution set of:

> $$Ax = 0$$

Is known as the *kernel* of $A$.
It's easy to prove that $\ker A$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$.
This means if $V = \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\ker A$ is either $\{0\}$, a line, a plane, or $\mathbb{R}^3$, as these are the only possible vector subspaces.

The "size" of a solution set depends on what's called the *nullity* of the matrix $A$.
Essentially, start with the matrix $A$, and row reduce it:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & \dots &  1\\
\vdots & & \ddots & 1\\
\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The number of "all 0" columns is the nullity, and tells you how big the solution set to $Ax = 0$ is.
If there are no all 0 columns, it'll be a point, if there's 1 it'll be a line, 2 it'll be a plane, etc.

Comment: Okay, but writing the solution in the parametric form, having n free variables can also be used to deduce what the solution set represents, right?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan yes, and if you have $n$ linearly-independent generators of the solution set, it'll be of dimension $n$.